# What "mobile" questions are good for superuser.com?

Tags: discussion, mobile

What "mobile" questions are suitable for superuser.com?

If I ask how to configure a certain handset model so that the alarm clock rings in vibrate mode, then it seems to me this is 100% mobile and not computer related.

If I ask how to setup email-fetching from my company server for a certain handset, this does seems computer related.

Where is the limit, what mobile questions, if at all, should be asked in superuser.com?

Answer (score 7):

Mobile phone questions are generally frowned upon unless you are asking how to perform some actions with them along with a computer. For example: asking how to download images from a phone onto a pc.

On the other hand, smart phones like Blackberries, iPhones, Windows Mobile devices, those are generally much more accepted because they can fit into the definition of a consumer computer much more easily.